# Remove white space under footer

Tags: css, layout

How to remove white space under footer bar? I already remove padding:15px under footer, but its not working.

Here's the [site](http://goo.gl/49elyC)

CSS

```
#bottom-footer{ 
background: #909090;
text-transform: initial;
padding: 15px;
font-family: 'Arial', 'sans-serif';
color: #000000;
font-weight: 300;
}
#bottom-footer .site-info{
float: left;
font-size: 14px;
color: #000;
line-height: 1.8;
}
#bottom-footer .site-page{
float: right;
font-size: 14px;
line-height: 1.8;
color:#D00000;
}
#bottom-footer .copyright{
float: right;
padding-top:20px;
margin-left:600px;
}
#bottom-footer .logos{
float: left;
padding-top:20px;
margin-right:50px;
}
```

Comment: do you mean, you want to make the footer stick to the bottom of the window?

Answer (score 6):

I'm assuming you want your footer to stick to the bottom of the window except for when the content is higher then the window.. I suggest a few things:

1. Fix your html, for example, all your content is inside your header tag, that's probably a mistake.
2. To make your footer work correctly, I would use the css calc method to give your content a minimum height of 100% minus the height of your header+footer, as such (notice also a few important css rules to make this work):

**html,body,#page,header { height:100%;}**

```
#content {
  min-height: calc(100% - 285px); // 285 should be the height of your header + height of footer.
}
```

** Notice that calc method needs to be written exactly as above (spaces and all) to work.. [browser support link](http://caniuse.com/#search=calc)

### Option 2

Another way you can achieve this:

```
html,body,#page, header { height:100%;}

#page { position:relative;}
#content { padding-bottom:130px;} /* FOOTER HEIGHT */
footer { position:absolute; bottom:0;}
```

If you have any question feel free..

Answer (score 0):

Try giving dynamic `margin-bottom` value to your **#content**

So the `margin-bottom` value will be same as the height of your **footer**

Comment: I put margin-bottom:0px but its still not remove

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use this 
http://ryanfait.com/html5-sticky-footer/

```
Keeps footer always to the bottom


* {
        margin: 0;
}
html, body {
        height: 100%;
}
.wrapper {
        min-height: 100%;
        margin: 0 auto -155px; /* the bottom margin is the negative value of the footer's height */
}
footer, .push {
        height: 155px; /* '.push' must be the same height as 'footer' */
}

/*
```