# Get Rid of White Space Under Footer On Full Screen Browser And Large (49 inch) Screens

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

Frankly I have seen and read so many posts on this topic to the point that I almost shied away from asking the question but none has covered the scope of or solved my problem so far. 
I get white screen on [this](http://www.photomaverick.org/tr/hakkimda/) website only when I put the browser on full screen (press F11). The space is even worse on large screens such as 49 inch televisions if their browsers are also put to full screen mode. I am using blankslate theme and used elementor plugin to build the site so I dont have an "official" footer per say. How best can I get rid of this because it looks really ugly on huge screens. Solutions such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26202321/remove-white-space-under-footer) and the like but they dont work including setting the

> height: 100vh; //100% /* in custom.css */

Comment: What have you already tried? Any examples? A http://jsfiddle.net ?

Comment: @Dan White. tried putting over-flow: hidden on the lowest section that has my footer, height: 100% and 100hv of the body tag... wanted to include them all but it seems I have limited citations(2 to be exact). Can't make more than that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay a few things:
Your body has margin of 8px on it:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
}
```

You want to put height: 100vh; on the inner container of the content. It also has margin-top: -1%; for some reason:

```
.elementor-element-9q9c7yv {
    height: 100vh;
    margin-top: 0; 
}
```

This fixes everything except there is an empty div on the bottom that is adding 1px of white space to the footer, get rid of it:

```
elementor-container elementor-column-gap-no {
    display: none;
}
```

There ya go :)

Comment: hello, steve thanks. that actually solved it for that page. Yes that div is hidden to play music when I click pm in black to reveal other pages. Margin: -1 was to avoid unecessary scrolls but thats not an issue. I can live with it if it cant be helped.  My question is, how did you figure out which class (.elementor-element-9q9c7yv) to add the height property to to solve it. So that I dont bother you for the other pages on the site. Thanks. When you click the pm in black other pages are revealed. still they still have the issue. But now at least I know where to look :)

Comment: Hey Gordon, mark me as the answer and i'll give you my secret: Honestly I just used inspect element and tried putting 100vh on the outer container, but the inner content was still short so I kept going deeper down the DOM until the right container was selected. This particular element had like 20 classes on it, but I saw that the 9q9c7yv class wasn't used anywhere else. If you know your code base and there aren't a ridiculous amount of elementor classes everywhere it is a lot easier to narrow down these problems. Also just years of development experience helps me know where to look ;)

Comment: Sure, I have marked the answer - thats no problem. I tried what you said before posting the comment. But couldnt get any class on any of the remaining pages. No luck yet :(.

Comment: Sure let me look at a different page real quick I'm just being lazy

Comment: ahh, the last container? or the container with the "body" content in it? lol. I guess laziness is a general problem in this field :).

Comment: It is elementor-container elementor-column-gap-no, I can see on this page http://www.photomaverick.org/tr/hakkimda/. You can set that to calc(100vh - 210px) which is the full height - the height of your header banners... actually wait a lot of elements have that class

Comment: This is probably the best selector I can get for you: .elementor-section-full_width.elementor-section-height-min-height .elementor-section-height-default.elementor-section-items-middle > .elementor-container { height: calc(100vh - 210px); }

Comment: ok, that doesnt actually do it. But I think I get the idea, Thanks :)
Why the downvote btw :( ?

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
```

If that doesn't work, you could put this plus the above:

```
footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}
```